# Get part of a URL after domain using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a URL, for example: `http://www.di.fm/calendar/event/40351`

I want to parse this URL with a regular expression, and retrieve the part after domain.  In this case :`calendar/event/40351`

There can also be additional information after a hash: (e.g., `calendar/event/40351#event-info`)

Comment: Is it this specific domain you need to handle, or any arbitrary domain?

Comment: arbitrary domain,.. some string for example

Comment: This is no simple question, and you would be better off not using a regex.  The linked question has some answers, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need Regex:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.di.fm/calendar/event/40351#123");
var result = uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;
```